# WPF: copying of XmlElement

Tags: wpf, xml

I create a window in WPF.  The constructor takes a "ref XmlElement settings" which is used to display information in that window.

In the constructor, I clone those settings:

```
_ClonedSettings = (XmlElement)settings.Clone();
```

and I keep a pointer to the original settings:

_OriginalSettings = settings;

The UI modifies `_ClonedSettings`. Then if user hits OK button, I want to overwrite the original settings with the `_ClonedSettings`, so the window creator gets the right values.

How do I do this final copying operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a ref.  Just set the settings as a public property on the window

```
public class SettingsEditor : Window
{ 
  public XmlElement Settings {get;set;}
  /*...*/
}
```

Within the Window, update the settings and such as you've done.  Once the window has been shown, get the settings out.

```
/*...*/
var editor = new SettingsEditor { Settings = settings };
editor.ShowDialog();
settings = editor.Settings;
/*...*/
```

You can also set a DialogResult on your window to see what happened with the editor...